# Function avcodec_open2 returns 0xbebbb1b7

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I know what does it mean? How can I analyze this value? This happened when I upgraded the ffmpeg version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is negative of 0x41444E49 which looks like:

`#define AVERROR_INVALIDDATA        FFERRTAG( 'I','N','D','A') ///< Invalid data found when processing input`

You can check error codes from `avutils/error.h`:https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/error.h